# Drupal custom form remembering textfield data

Tags: php, forms, drupal, module, textfield

I am setting up a configuration page for a new module and I am having trouble getting my textfield to remember data I previously entered.

I am setting #default_value by calling variable_get but the value never gets reset in the textfield. It is however correctly stored as a variable and visible on the variable editor page.

Below is a code fragment:

```
$form   =   array();

$form['username']   =   array(
    '#type'                     =>  'textfield',
    '#title'                    =>  t('Username'),
    '#default_value'            =>  variable_get('username', '' ),
    '#description'              =>  t('supply the username'),
    '#maxlength'                =>  30,
    '#required'                 =>  TRUE,
    '#weight'                   =>  -1,
);

return system_settings_form($form);
```

How can I fix this?

### Updated code

The submit function is as follows:

```
    function mymodule_settings_submit($form, &$form_state){
    drupal_set_message('form submit responding : ' . $form_state['values']['username'] );
    variable_set( 'username', $form_state['values']['username'] );
}
```

### Updated code #2

The full code:

```
    function my_module_init(){
}

function my_module_menu(){

    $items = array();
    $items['admin/settings/helper'] =   array(
        'title'                     =>  'helper',
        'page callback'             => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments'            =>  array('helper_setup'),
        'access arguments'          =>  array('access administration pages'),
        'type'                      =>  MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,

    );
    return $items;

}

function helper_setup(){

    $node_types =   node_get_types('names');

    $form   =   array();

    $form['username']   =   array(
        '#type'                     =>  'textfield',
        '#title'                    =>  t('Username'),
        '#default_value'            =>  variable_get('username', '' ),
        '#description'              =>  t('supply the username'),
        '#maxlength'                =>  30,
        '#required'                 =>  TRUE,
        '#weight'                   =>  -1,
    );

    $form['#submit'][] =    'my_module_settings_submit';

    return system_settings_form($form);
}

function my_module_validate($form, &$form_state){
    die('validation area responding!');
}

function my_module_settings_submit($form, &$form_state){
    drupal_set_message('form submit responding : ' . $form_state['values']['username'] );
    variable_set( 'username', $form_state['values']['username'] );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your form submit function you should insert `variable_set('variableName' , 'value')` variables is not inserted automatically..

**UPDATE:**

```
$form['username']   =   array(
    '#type'                     =>  'textfield',
    '#title'                    =>  t('Username'),
    '#default_value'            =>  variable_get('username', '' ),
    '#description'              =>  t('supply the username'),
    '#maxlength'                =>  30,
    '#required'                 =>  TRUE,
    '#weight'                   =>  -1,
);

$form['#submit'][] = '_myform_submit_function' ; 
return system_settings_form($form);
```

now lets build your submit function

```
function _myform_submit_function($form,&$form_state ) {
variable_set('username', $form_state['values']['username']) ; 
drupal_set_message('form submit responding : ' . $form_state['values']['username'] );
}
```

now clear the cache and tell me if its working or not

Comment: thanks. I had tried your approach but it didn't work. The second argument is supposed to be the default if the first does not exist. Since the value provided in the textfield is saved as a drupal value when the form is submitted, the first argument of the variable_set function should contain that value and populate the textfield when the page refreshes - but it's not working ???

Comment: can i see your form submit function ?

Comment: The submit function is doing very little. I am simply calling drupal_set_message and outputting the value of the textfield from within $form_state array. It confirms the supplied value as entered by the user but the issue is then to set that value back into the textfield

Comment: '#default_value'            =>  variable_get('username', '' ),  

.... how variable_get is calling variable is not exist you should call variable_set('username' , $form_state['values']['username']);  to set the value of the form to variable named username ... then calling this value from variable_get

Comment: I've included the form submit function in the code above. I carried out your suggestion but it didn't work ... unless I missed the point and did something wrong ???

Comment: i have updated my answer please check it and don't forget to clear the cache

Comment: I think it's exaactly as I had previously done ... it didn't work. I included the full code above if you'll like to examine it.

Comment: drupal_set_message is working with you ? .. and the value you insert in the form is appeared in the message ? .. and which version of drupal core you use

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4067/discussion-between-sisko-and-maged-adel)

Comment: thanks maged, it came down to a simple type and your solution worked.